# What do the parameters used in crop mean?

Tags: cnn, computer-vision, image-segmentation, image-size

When we have an image to be used as an input to a CNN and we want to classify only part of the image, we usually feed the classifier with a crop of the image.

Lets say my image is called frame and `x`, `y`, `w` and `h` are `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax` and `ymax`, respectively:

```
frame = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w] #Crop a part of the image
```

What does `y:y` or `x:x` mean and why do we sum them to `h` and `w`, respectively?

I've been seeing some people performing the crop in the following way:

```
frame = frame[y:h, x:w] #Crop a part of the image without adding to `w` and `h`
```

I saw the second approach being used in some places like in the following line: https://github.com/balajisrinivas/Face-Mask-Detection/blob/master/detect_mask_video.py#L51

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lets say my image is called frame and x, y, w and h are xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax

You're confusing $w$ with $xmax$ and $h$ with $ymax$: Usually $w$ is the **width** of the crop whereas $xmax$ is the **horizontal position** of the end of the crop. Similarly $h$ is the height and $ymax$ is the vertical position of the end of the crop.

Logically since $x$ is the (horizontal) start of the crop and $w$ is the width, we can obtain $xmax$ like this: $xmax=x+w$.

Example: in a 100x100 image, let's say we want to crop a 20x20 square in the centre: $x=40, y=40, w=20, h=20, xmax=60, ymax=60$.

In the following code:

> ```
> frame = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
> ```

the operator `:` is used to represent a sequence (for instance `3:7` means `3,4,5,6`) so `y:y + h` represents the sequence from `y` to `y+h`, i.e. from $y$ to $ymax$. Same for `x+w`, so this line would select the part of the array corresponding to the crop.

Your second example is wrong due to the same confusion, the actual code is:

```
face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
```

In this case the author is directly using the end coordinate `endY` (same as $ymax$) instead of calculating it as `startY+h`.

Comment: What an amazing explanation. Thank you very much Erwan!